# How automatically be logged in to both the Control Panel and front-end at the same time?

Tags: members, control-panel, login, users

If user logged in to front-end, is it possible to auto logged in to Control Panel ?

How automatically be logged in to both the Control Panel and front-end at the same time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens anyway (at least with Super Admin accounts). Maybe the more recent versions of EE introduce an extra level of security but I just tested this on a site running 2.6.1 and logging in on the front end also allowed me to access the CP without having to log in again.

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed correct:) unless the member group doesn't have access to the CP I can't see any reason why this wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't appear to be check that your base URLs match - IE you aren't logged in at a "www." URL and viewing at a non-www url. Or vice-versa.